# How to increase the number of observations in xts object by taking previous value?

Tags: r, datetime, xts

**What I have:**

```
dta <- xts(
  c(1,2,3,4),
  order.by = timeDate(c(
     "2000-01-01 00:01:01",
     "2000-01-01 00:01:05",
     "2000-01-01 00:01:06",
     "2000-01-01 00:01:07"
     )
  )
)

                    [,1]
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1
2000-01-01 00:05:00    2
2000-01-01 00:06:00    3
2000-01-01 00:07:00    4
```

**What I need:**

```
                    [,1]
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1
2000-01-01 00:02:00    1
2000-01-01 00:03:00    1
2000-01-01 00:04:00    1
2000-01-01 00:05:00    2
2000-01-01 00:06:00    3
2000-01-01 00:07:00    4
```

Similar questions on stackoverflow only deal with decreasing the periodicity of an `xts` object and did not help me with this problem.

I am cleaning minute price data, where prices where only recorded if there actually where trades. Obviously, if there where no trades this means that the price stays the same as in the previous minute.

Comment: Please provide `dput` of your data. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315885/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-r-data-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge it with a zero width sequence (grid) having the required times:

```
rng <- range(time(dta))
g <- xts(, seq(rng[1], rng[2], by = 1))
na.locf(merge(dta, g))
```